# Ergonomic Option handling inside Ref::map

Tags: rust

I have a function that tries to return a `Ref` out of a `Refcell`. The reference is behind an `Option`, and I'd like to be able to return the reference or an error if the `Option` is `None`.

Currently, I am checking beforehand if there it is none and returning an error if it is. Afterwards, I am calling `unwrap()` on the Option inside `Ref::map` in order to return the object.

Is there a more ergonomic way to do this? This seems very annoying to do (multiple borrows(), etc.) `Option` has a method `ok_or` that turns it into a Result type. Is there a way to use that here?

Here is a [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5847da00f7b7c60e02a3975ca85e3c59) to reproduce the minimal example:

```
    pub fn get_thing_convenience(&self) -> Result<Ref<f32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        if self.thing.borrow().is_none() {
            return Err(Box::new(MyError("blah".into())))
        }
        let thing = Ref::map(self.thing.borrow(), |t| t.unwrap());

        Ok(thing)
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have added a Rust playground link and significantly reworded my question.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a `filter_map` method, but it was removed because the functionality can (usually?) be implemented safely with a performance cost, and it wasn't clear whether `filter_map` was the best way to go (it would special-case `Option`, complicates things with the recent changes/debate over `Try`, and it might just make more sense for there to be a way to transform `Ref<Option<T>>` into `Option<Ref<T>>`). However, in the meantime, there is a crate [`ref_filter_map`](https://crates.io/crates/ref_filter_map) that does exactly this and is "believed to be safe".

You could use it like this:

```rust
use ref_filter_map::ref_filter_map;

pub fn get_thing_convenience(&self) -> Result<Ref<f32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    ref_filter_map(self.thing.borrow(), |t| t)
        .ok_or_else(|| Box::new(MyError("blah".into())))
}
```

However, you may want to consider simply doing it the slow way if you are worried about unsafety.